# Parse.com could not push notification to multiple devices android

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push

My application used Parse to push notification to multiple devices. But only one devices can receive that notification. I don't know why? Please help me. Here're some code :

AppController:

```
 // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_app_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("RadaBikeSp", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                Log.d("Success", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("Fail", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

in Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<permission
    android:name="thsoft.com.sosme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="thsoft.com.sosme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
    android:name=".services.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconapp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="thsoft.com.sosme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/iconapp" />
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to access to internet for using parse push notification.
please add this permission to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the GCM registration key from your fullBackupContent like here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutoBackupForApps